# How to use MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.query?

Tags: android, cursor, thumbnails, mediastore

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html

I am trying last three methods to get thumbnail from Uri.

But Cursor remains null. Please help how to use it? Basically I want to get Micro sized thumbnail (generated by android) from the image stored on sdcard.

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.query(getContentResolver(),
        Uri.parse("file://" + "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110722_101000.jpg"), null);
if (cursor != null) {
    Log.d("sf","Sfsfs");
}
```

Also tried following one:

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(getContentResolver(),
        Uri.parse("file://" + "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110722_101000.jpg"), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    Log.d("sf","Sfsfs");
}
```

I am not trying any method where it requires `long origId` as a parameter, as I have only path not ID.

Comment: I think i need to use content style uri, How to convert it from absolute path?

Comment: It requires MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI as parameter, i.e. Uri should be like: `content://media/external/images/media`. Is there any way to get this styled uri from `file:///mnt/sdcard/Camera`???

Answer (score 0):

Make a query to ContentResolver to obtain your thumbnails

```
Cursor thumbnails = contentResolver.query(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(photoId)}, null);
```

You can get photoId from its URI, to get URI from file name just create File and parse URI from it

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Answer (score -5):

well,you should call `cursor.moveToNext()` after the query.

Comment: a null cursor cannot be moved to next:)